# How to include additional information Course Overview Block in Moodle 3.8

Tags: moodle

I am working in LMS application which we are developing in Moodle 3.8. One of our requirement is need to add the Enroll End date in Course Overview Block in Dashboard page.

I am unable to find the place to add/override the details in Course Overview block

Please help me to do this change,

Answer (score 0):

You will need to overrider the block code itself to show the end date. You will find it under

```
moodle/block/myoverview
```